# errors in external javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript that works when placed in the head of my html.
It dynamically changes a background image in a div 'bg'.

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = function () {
    var header = document.getElementById('bg');
    var pictures = new Array('http://someurl.com/bgs/1.jpg',
                             'http://someurl.com/bgs/2.jpg',
                             'http://someurl.com/bgs/3.jpg',
                             'http://someurl.com/bgs/4.jpg',
                             'http://someurl.com/bgs/5.jpg');
    var numPics = pictures.length;
    if (document.images) {
        var chosenPic = Math.floor((Math.random() * numPics));
        header.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + pictures[chosenPic] + ')';</script>
```

I would like to use it as an external .js file, but when I save the script as dynamicbg1.js and call it like this:
`<script src="http://someurl.com/js/dynamicbg1.js"></script>` 
I get errors, and the images won't load.
this is is the error I get:
"SyntaxError: missing } after function body"
 but when I append a } like this in dynamicbg1.js:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var header = document.getElementById('bg');
    var pictures = new Array('http://someurl.com/bgs/1.jpg',
                             'http://someurl.com/bgs/2.jpg',
                             'http://someurl.com/bgs/3.jpg',
                             'http://someurl.com/bgs/4.jpg',
                             'http://someurl.com/bgs/5.jpg');
    var numPics = pictures.length;
    if (document.images) {
        var chosenPic = Math.floor((Math.random() * numPics));
        header.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + pictures[chosenPic] + ')';
    }
```

I get the same error.
Can anyone help me get the script to work as an external .js file?

Comment: try to be more thorough, dude!

Answer (score 3):

When you append the `}` you are closing the block you opened with `if (document.images) {`.

That still leaves the function open.

You need another `}`.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment? I mean, it's basically a simple bugfix?